# rails rename table with id_seq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i rename table

```
rename_table :posts, :messages
```

but rails generate posts_id_seq and posts.id Modifiers:

```
db=# \d+ posts
                                                Table "public.posts"
       Column         |            Type             |                           Modifiers                           | Storage  | Description 
id                    | integer                     | not null default nextval('posts_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 

Indexes:
    "posts_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

How to correct rename table?

ruby 1.8.7

rails 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a change to fix that behavior was merged into Rails several months ago (see issue [#6864](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6874)), but the fix likely is not present in Rails 2.3 series. You would need to use Rails 4 (still in development/beta) to have the fix.

Comment: could has commands that can be performed for manual correction?

Comment: See the [diffs](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6874/files) for that issue, but it basically boils down to `ALTER TABLE <old seq name> RENAME TO <new seq name>`

Comment: when i run ALTER TABLE posts RENAME TO messages, postgressql only rename table and Indexes/Foreign-key not modified.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question... To rename the index you would need to use `rename_index` in your Rails migration. To rename the sequence, run `ALTER TABLE posts_id_seq RENAME TO messages_id_seq` in SQL

Comment: Thank you for your answer to my question.

Comment: Hmm... I ran into the same problem with rails 4.1.4